# How to move the group of data to the next page if end of page splits the group?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-reports

I developed a lab database in Access. I am trying to create a report of lab tests.

If the tests exceed the page the group of tests divides (some tests printed on one page and some printed on the next page).

I have attached Lab Report in which some of Lipid Profile tests are on one page and the rest on the next page. I want if the end of page is reached the complete group (Lipid Profile) of tests shifts to the next page.

Page1 of Lab Report
[image]

Page 2 of Lab Report
[image]

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `GroupLevel.KeepTogether` property to "Whole group" = 1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.grouplevel.keeptogether

In the UI, you set this in **Group, Sort and Total**, see e.g. here:

https://access-excel.tips/access-report-keep-a-group-together-in-one-page/